# EF Saving only the 1st child entity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to save an Event and EventDetails corresponding to that event.
It's saving the Event and the 1st **EventDetail** from the loop only.

```
public class Event
{
    [Key]
    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    ..
    public virtual ICollection<EventDetail> EventDetails{ get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Event ev)
{
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            IQueryable<EventDetail> eventList = ..;

            FutureEvents fe = new FutureEvents();
            ICollection<FutureEvents> feCol = new Collection<FutureEvents>();

            foreach (EventDetail det in eventList)
            {
                fe.Name = ..;
                db.Entry(fe).State = EntityState.Added;
                feCol.Add(fe);
            }

            ev.EventDetails = feCol;
            db.Event.Add(ev);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(ev);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move

```
FutureEvents fe = new FutureEvents();
```

within `foreach` loop. You created exactly one `FutureEvents`, so one is saved.

Comment: well i can't believe I did that!!

Answer (score 1):

You have created a single object then modified it in every iteration. Try this out:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Event ev)
{
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            IQueryable<EventDetail> eventList = ..;

            ICollection<FutureEvents> feCol = new Collection<FutureEvents>();

            foreach (EventDetail det in eventList)
            {
                FutureEvents fe = new FutureEvents();
                fe.Name = ..;
                db.Entry(fe).State = EntityState.Added;
                feCol.Add(fe);
            }

            ev.EventDetails = feCol;
            db.Event.Add(ev);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(ev);
}
```